# JsColor destroy

Tags: jquery, color-picker, jscolor

How to remove a jscolor method bound to an input box ?

I have a textbox with id "bgColor" and jscolor is binded using jsColor.installByClassName("jscolor").

Now I want to remove that functionality from that textbox.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research on that area, it is confirmed that there are no explicit method available to achieve this. There are some ways like,

1. In the JsColor script library you can implement your own method to destroy the jscolor from the corresponding input element.
2. You can prevent the Color picker being popped up on clicking the input element, by modifying the code to open the Color picker.